# Run and Save multiple SELECT statements

Tags: postgresql, select

Within a Postgres function I would like to run a number of `SELECT` commands. For each `SELECT` command I would like to output written to separate text files.

What is the best way to implement this?

PostgreSQL version: 9.3.5.0

```
 BEGIN

 RETURN QUERY SELECT text 
    FROM eightks
    WHERE other_events = true 
    AND text ~* '(\y(chief executive officer)\y)'
    AND text ~*'(\y(cancer)\y)'          
    \o /Users/XXXX/desktop/test.txt;

 RETURN QUERY SELECT text
    FROM eightks
    WHERE other_events = true 
    AND text ~* '(\y(chief executive officer)\y)'
    AND text ~* '(\y(sudden)\y)' 
    \o /Users/xxxx/desktop/sudden.txt;

  END
```

Here is the follow ERROR message

```
    edgar=# \i test3.sql;
    psql:test3.sql:21: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
    LINE 2: RETURN QUERY SELECT text 
    ^
```

Here is also the structure of the table if it helps;

```
     edgar=# \d eightks
           Table "public.eightks"
       Column    |   Type   | Modifiers 
   --------------+----------+-----------
    id           | integer  | 
    doc_id       | bigint   | 
    text         | text     | 
    tsv          | tsvector | 
    other_events | boolean  |
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing PL/PgSQL with SQL.

You do not need the `RETURN QUERY`, nor is it valid in normal SQL.

Simply `SELECT text FROM eightks` ...

Additionally, if you want to direct output to a particular file with `psql`'s `\o`, you must run the `\o` command *before* the statement you want to write the output for.

Finally - I wonder if you should be looking into the `\copy` command, if you're trying to write query output to files.

```
\copy (SELECT ....) TO '/some/file' WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

Comment: Yep. `COPY` all the way.

Comment: Also worth noting that from within a function (if it is really needed in this case) one cannot split the output to separate files (well, no file handling at all, unless one goes `pl/python` or something).  A function has only one result set, regardless how many statements produce the output.